# Trying to sum values in excel table using column data comparisons and sumif

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I haven't been able to find an exact answer to this question, so I'm hoping someone out there knows the answer.   Basically, I have a table of imported regional sales data by date in an Excel workbook from which I am then trying to sum values for certain products sold on that date.

I've given names to the columns in the imported data to make it easier -- 'date', 'office', 'product', 'qty', 'avgPrice', etc....

**Imported Table**

```
DATE       PRODUCT     OFFICE     QTY     PRICE
3/4/2020   CAP-A       ILLICH     5       $4.19
3/1/2020   CAP-A       TOPEKA     3       $4.26
3/3/2020   RAD-C       ILLICH     7       $7.19
3/4/2020   RAD-B       ILLICH     2       $7.02
3/4/2020   CAP-A       TOPEKA     10      $4.17
3/1/2020   CAP-A       TOPEKA     7       $4.23
3/3/2020   RAD-A       ILLICH     9       $6.98
3/1/2020   CAP-A       TOPEKA     2       $4.21
```

**Desired output**

```
DATE       PRODUCT     Total_QTY
3/1/2020   CAP-A       12       
3/2/2020   CAP-A       0
3/3/2020   CAP-A       0
3/4/2020   CAP-A       15
```

The formula I'm using is:  =SUMIFS(qty,date,"=[@DATE]",product,"=[@PRODUCT]")

The problem is, this will always return a sum of "0" for that entry incorrectly.   However, if I make the change where instead of using "=[@DATE]" is manually input the date as "=3/1/2020", and replace "=[@PRODUCT]" with "=CAP-A", then I get the correct results.

Of course, I can go through and input the date and product manually, but I have hundreds of dates right now and several products, and this will likely turn into thousands over time, and I may have to import new figures using the same framework but with historical records, so different dates and products.   I don't want to have to type out these comparisons manually every time

Is there something simple I'm overlooking here, or a way of comparing the the two fields I'm not aware of?

Answer (score 0):

well, as usual, taking time to post the question, somehow allows me to arrive at the answer myself, SMH....

I just needed to not use the "" and =.   So, =SUMIFS(qty,date,[@DATE],product,[@PRODUCT]) returns the correct results.